# how use plugin jquery in framework7

Tags: android, phonegap-plugins, cordova-plugins, html-framework-7

I am trying to build a mobile application with Cordova and I have chosen the framework named "framework7". In the application I have HTML page have textboxes time, when the user clicks on the textbox clock picker will be display
 (clockpicker jquery plugin) 
Now the main issue is that  the framework7 doesn't allow the jquery plugins to work with it
can anyone help me

Answer (score 2):

ofcourse jquery works with cordova i used jquery for all my app that i wrote with cordova .dowload jquery and add your project.and u should be careful where u write, u need to write it before framework7.js because it uses it

this is my general usage i added jquery.js that i downloaded to lib folder

```
<script src="cordova.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/platformOverrides.js"></script>
    <script src="lib/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
    <script src="lib/framework7.min.js"></script>
    <script src="lib/my-app.js"></script>

    <script src="scripts/index.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/Home.js"></script>
```

Comment: jquery is working now but the plugin did not work,I wondered why any plugin jquery did not work with FW7

Comment: which plugin are u using

Comment: share your sort of scripts, in html

Comment: <input type="text" class="clockpicker"/>  
$('.clockpicker').clockpicker({
                //placement: 'top',
                align: 'left',
                donetext: 'Done',
                autoclose: false ,
                //  default: '10:00',
                twelvehour: true

            });
</script>

Comment: I see something platformOverrides.js I did not put this am I must put this js file , if yes from where I can download it

Answer (score 0):

You must run it on initpage on each js function

Answer (score 0):

You have to write all your your short jQuery function  inside the 
myApp.onPageInit(' ', function(){});

Other wise the jQuery code will not work properly